# dyld: Lybrary not loaded. Error in terminarl after installing XCode Beta 10

Tags: xcode, terminal, zsh, dyld, xcode10

I recently installed XCode Beta 10 and afterwards, this message appears on the top of the terminal prompt every time I open it:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/gdbm/lib/libgdbm.4.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/zsh
  Reason: image not found
zsh: abort
```

I checked the /usr/local/opt/gdbm/lib/ directory and the `libgdbm.4.dylib`file is indeed missing, but a `libgdbm.4.dylib`file is in there. What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to fix this by simply running `brew reinstall zsh`.